# Creat new instance of different model from user input in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller, model

I am developing an app where the user can assing tags to pictures. The first time he uploads a picture he does not have the opportunity to assign tags. However these tags can be changed with the help of the best_in_place gem. This will call the update action in the pictures controller.

Here I will get these tags trough the params hash. I am now trying to create a new instance of the tags-model for each tag, that is found in the params hash. Unfortunately though, I dont know, how I would do that. So that would be my first question, since I could not link the form directly to the tags-controller.

Another question: If I created those tags, I don't want to store the tags itself in the according coloumn in the picture-table, but the ids of those tags I just created. How would I need to manipulate the update action to make that happen?

Currently the update action looks like so:

```
def update
  @model = Pictures.find params[:id]
  respond_do |format|
    params[:pictures][:tags] do |tag|
      tag = @tags.new <- create new tags here
    end
    if @model.update_attributes(params[:pictures])
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@model) }
      format.json { redirect_to action: 'show', status: :created, location: @model }
    end
end
```

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails so it might be an easy question, however any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, what are the associations between Pictures and Tags?? A tag can have many pictures & A Picture can have many tags? I mean a `has_many :through` association?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned this. You are right. A picture can have many tags (has_many :tags), but a tag does not need to belong to only one picture, which would be has_many :pictures.

Comment: So, you must be having a join table where you want to store the tag_id and the picture_id. And what if the tag with the provided name does already exist?

Comment: Well actually I was planning to store the tag_id in a coloumn in pictures, named tag_ids or whatever and use the tag id from the corresponding tag out of the tags-table. If a tag already exists in the tags-table I want to use the corresponding id of the existing tag, since it would make no sense to create a new tag.

Comment: So in that case, you can't have many to many relationship between tags and pictures. I mean you can only store one tag per picture as there would be only one tag_id in the pictures table. If you're trying to store a comma separated list of ids?

Comment: I was indeed planning on storing a comma separated list of ids. Like I said: I am fairly new to rails, so if that is not ideal, I see no reason not to use a join-table.

Comment: Yes, you should better use a join table to get most of the active record associations.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html correctly I would be best of to use a has_many :through association. So I am going to need to build this first, and than come back to the original question above

Comment: Yes. You can use `has many :through` if you want to keep any additional fields in the join table. Otherwise you can use any of `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has many :through`.

Comment: Ok, so according to google I would still need to create a join-table with a migration then, which is named pictures_tags and would then add an entry to that table, every time the user assigns a new tag to a picture? As for the pictures model I would not need any column which holds the tags id, right?